# Can you create a custom property under an object in Visual Basic?

Tags: basic

I am writing some code where I am using a single event handler for multiple labels, and I would like to add a custom property of a value from 0 to 8 so that I can organise the inputs into an array. For example (see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oqxux.png)), I've got a 3x3 grid of Xs, I want to add a number 0 to 8 (0 being the top left and 8 being the bottom right, where it moves across the row then down a row), so that I can know which label has been clicked on. So far I have this, but I would like to replace *i* with something such as sender.pos (Positional index of the sender object, where pos is a property of the sender). This is what I have so far, the [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anfaz.png) is for a game of TicTacToe. Let me know if I've been unclear. I would love some help on this!

Comment: You can use the Tag property to store values.  Which version of VB are you using?

Comment: I think its 4.01, but I'm not 100% sure. Also can you add multiple numbers to the tag property, e.g. have a coordinate (x, y) pair such as 1, 2.

Comment: The tag property is alpha-numeric, so you can store any text in there.  It would be up to you, of course, to split the coordinates back again when reading the tags, though.  I use the tag property for various things, even multiple kinds of data and surround them with delimiters like {} and () etc. so I can easily parse them later in the code, but a simple set of coordinates could be stored simply as "x,y"